# PowerShell 'get-ClusterQuorum' output is not showing 'QuorumType' column

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-clustering

PowerShell cmdlet 'get-ClusterQuorum' output is not showing "QuorumType" column. Has anybody seen this before? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is just the normal output for that cmdlet. To see `QuorumType`, you can use these methods:

```powershell
$quorum = Get-ClusterQuorum -Cluster CLUSTER
$quorum | Select-Object *
$quorum.QuorumType

$quorum | Format-Table * # For display only
$quorum | Format-List *  # For display only
```

Many cmdlets control which columns get displayed by default, but the underlying properties are still there and can be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to view it is just to run this:

```
(Get-ClusterQuorum).QuorumType
```

This is a nice neat little way to do these things on one line without having to create a variable explicitly.